# Query regarding python database programming

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using the below code to delete a row from sqlite table.

```
def deleteFromTable(item):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("lite.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM store WHERE item=?", (item,))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Why do i need to use comma after item (item,) while passing the argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`('String')` evaluates into string, but `('string',)` evaluates into tuple. that's why you need comma.

Comment: Thank you very much